# Display posts from category in post content?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am developing a website using WordPress. As I don't want the sidebar, I removed 'get_sidebar()' from my page. But I need to place a category in the content part (like a category for latest news) - not in a sidebar. How could I do this?

Comment: You mean like a archive list of posts from a certain category?

Comment: Yes..how could i do this..?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a query

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

You can put that in your category page or in something like [Exec-PHP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/)

For looking up the current category you can grab it like

```
get_query_var('cat')
```